# Is there a way you can take a partial screenshot programmatically in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, screenshot

Is there a way you can take a partial screenshot programmatically in Android studio
For instance when take a screenshot and be able to crop the image before you save it

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKVJz.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Not built in.  You could write one yourself-  You'd have to take the full screenshot, but then you could crop the result.